# Changing projection in KML from Google Earth to Maps

Tags: google-maps, kml, google-earth, google-maps-api

I have created a bunch of map tiles for Google Maps mistakenly using the Google Earth projection. Is there a tool available to batch warp the KML files to the correct projection or will I need to generate the tiles again from scratch?

Comment: How did you create the tiles originally?

Comment: I used MapTiler with the output set to Google Earth KML as I didn't realise that Maps and Earth use a different projection. My map (in progress...) is at http://www.southdevonaonb.org.uk/cordialemapping/ and I have some old maps to add as image overlays, which I was hoping to do as KML overlays.

Comment: Google Maps API KML support is limited. You most like want to  use the custom tiles method here http://maps.forum.nu/v3/gm_customTiles.html

Answer (score 1):

Check out the open-source GDAL/OGR utilities - (the OGR part) http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html

**ogr2ogr.exe** is a command-line tool which can be used in the FOR loop in a batch file to go through all your files and transform them. (for example in windows you create a *.bat file and put your DOS code for looping there).
In the OGR link above there is also a nice example for reprojecting a shapefile, you can apply it to your KML file.